# How to delete a managed folder and its contents programmatically via hook_uninstall?

Tags: 7, files

My hook_update_N() implementation looks like this:

```
$directory2 = 'public://folder_name';
file_prepare_directory($directory2, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY | FILE_MODIFY_PERMISSIONS);
```

How can I remove "folder_name" and its contents in hook_uninstall using drupal's API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal doesn't consider a folder to be a group of files, and doesn't have a method for bulk deleting managed files (like it does for unmanaged files: `file_unmanaged_delete_recursive`). So you'll need to identify which files you want to delete manually. A query with `WHERE uri LIKE 'public://folder_name/%'` might be sufficient in this case, for example, but you'll know you're own setup better than I can guess.

Once you have a list of file IDs, load up the objects, loop through them, and call `file_delete` on each. If you have the File Entity module installed, you can shorten this by using [`file_delete_multiple()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!file_entity!file_entity.file_api.inc/function/file_delete_multiple/7), and just pass the IDs.

Once you're happy all the files have been deleted (you could stat the folder after running the loop), then remove the folder with [`drupal_rmdir()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/drupal_rmdir/7).

Bear in mind that `file_delete()` is not guaranteed to remove the file; other parts of the system can declare their interest in a managed file by way of the `file_usage` table. If you want to unconditionally remove files regardless of any other entity in the system that they're attached to, you can use the `file_usage_*` methods in [file.inc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/7).